# NPM error - Invalid version passed for target "chrome":

Tags: npm, babeljs

I get the following error when trying to run babel using NPM. I have no idea what this means, so If someone could point me in the right direction?

```
    throw e;
    ^

Error: Invalid version passed for target "chrome": "current.0.0". Versionsmust be in semver format (major.minor.patch) (While processing preset: 
"C:\\wamp64\\www\\afstuderen\\keeswerkt\\d3_node_editor\\node_modules\\babel-preset-env\\lib\\index.js")
at C:\wamp64\www\afstuderen\keeswerkt\d3_node_editor\node_modules\babel-preset-env\lib\index.js:69:13
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at isPluginRequired 
(C:\wamp64\www\afstuderen\keeswerkt\d3_node_editor\node_modules\babel-preset-env\lib\index.js:59:54)
at filterItem 
(C:\wamp64\www\afstuderen\keeswerkt\d3_node_editor\node_modules\babel-preset-env\lib\index.js:99:20)
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at buildPreset 
(C:\wamp64\www\afstuderen\keeswerkt\d3_node_editor\node_modules\babel-preset-env\lib\index.js:149:56)
at C:\wamp64\www\afstuderen\keeswerkt\d3_node_editor\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:317:46
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at OptionManager.resolvePresets 
(C:\wamp64\www\afstuderen\keeswerkt\d3_node_editor\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:275:20)
at OptionManager.mergePresets 
(C:\wamp64\www\afstuderen\keeswerkt\d3_node_editor\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:264:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! d3_node_editor@1.0.0 start: `babel-watch src/js/main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the d3_node_editor@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\edwij\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-05T11_36_12_009Z-debug.log
```